# Non-static Expression<Func<X>> with access to 'this'

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda, expression-trees

I have a database table `Item` and access it with linq-to-sql.

I can define a custom Method IsSpecial() for Items which returns true if the square root of Item.id is even:

```
partial class Item
{
    public static Expression<Func<Item, bool>> IsSpecial = (i => Math.Sqrt(i.Id)%2==0);
}
```

Then I can use that property in a linq-to-sql query like this:

```
 datacontext.Item.Where(Item.IsSpecial)
```

Now for aesthetic reasons, I want to make IsSpecial nonstatic and modify it so I can call it like this:

```
 datacontext.Item.Where(i => i.IsSpecial())
```

Ideally this would also allow combining of statements, which the above (working) snytax does not allow:

```
 datacontext.Item.Where(i => i.IsSpecial() && i.Id >100)
```

What is the correct syntax for defining this method?

This does not work:

```
partial class Item
{
    public Expression<Func<bool>> IsSpecial = ( () => Math.Sqrt(this.Id)%2==0 );
    // 'this' keyword not available in current context
}
```

---

*edit:*
I am beginning to suspect that I am asking for something that the syntax simply does not allow

I guess I can live with `datacontext.Item.Where(Item.IsSpecial).Where(i => i>100)`

Comment: BTW `datacontext.Item.Where(i => Item.IsSpecial(i))` wont compile.

Comment: Why are you defining an IsSpecial property of type Func instead of defining an IsSpecial method?  Or even just an IsSpecial property of type bool?

Comment: `datacontext.Item.Where(Item.IsSpecial)` will compile however.

Comment: @leppie: thanks, I messed up there; I have fixed the syntax

Comment: @Ann L.: because local methods cannot be used in a linq-to-sql query. The statement is not executed in C#, it is translated to SQL.

Comment: @HugoRune: Mixing code and expressions is always hard. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> partial class Item
> {
>     public static Expression<Func<Item, bool>> IsSpecial = (i => Math.Sqrt(i.Id)%2==0);
> }
> ```

Suggestion: add the `readonly` keyword.

> Then I can use that property in a linq-to-sql query like this:
>
> ```
> datacontext.Item.Where(Item.IsSpecial)
> ```

Right, because `Where` accepts a parameter of type `Expression<Func<Item, bool>>`, which `Item.IsSpecial` is.

> Now for aesthetic reasons, I want to make IsSpecial nonstatic and modify it so I can call it like this:
>
> ```
> datacontext.Item.Where(i => i.IsSpecial())
> ```

The reason this doesn't work is because `IsSpecial` isn't a function, it's an expression tree. `()` can only be applied to functions. An expression tree describes a function, but isn't one. You can create a real function using `expression.Compile()`:

```
datacontext.Item.Where(i => (IsSpecial.Compile()) (i))
```

However, this won't work, because again, `Where` is passed an expression tree, and `IsSpecial.Compile()` isn't actually called. LINQ to SQL tries to convert it to SQL, fails because it doesn't recognise `Expression.Compile`, and throws an exception.

However, if you could replace `(IsSpecial.Compile())` before LINQ to SQL were to see it...

That's where [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) comes in:

It provides just that bit of expression tree manipulation to get it working.

```
datacontext.Item.AsExpandable().Where(i => (IsSpecial.Compile()) (i))
```

The `.AsExpandable()` creates a wrapper around `datacontext.Item` to pre-filter the expression.

> Ideally this would also allow combining of statements, which the above (working) snytax does not allow:
>
> ```
> datacontext.Item.Where(i => i.IsSpecial() && i.Id >100)
> ```

No problem:

```
datacontext.Item.AsExpandable().Where(i => (IsSpecial.Compile()) (i) && i.Id > 100)
```

Comment: this looks very promising, will check it out, thanks! I am a bit sceptical about including another library just for this, but the link to linqkit also led me to http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx which seems to discuss this problem in greater detail

Answer (score 2):

You can use IsSpecial directly:

```
partial class Item
{
     public static Expression<Func<Item, bool>> IsSpecial = (i => Math.Sqrt(i.Id)%2==0);
}

datacontext.Item.Where(Item.IsSpecial)
```

Comment: +1 First solution that in fact will compile. I did however make a comment about the same thing at the time :)

Comment: Sorry, I messed up when copying the syntax in my initial question, this is what I meant to write. Ideally I would want to change this to something like `(NOT VALID:) datacontext.Item.Where(i=>i.isSpecial() && i.Id>100 && [more properties]`, however I am beginning to suspect that what I am asking is impossible

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the assignment to IsSpecial in a constructor and have all the other constructors delegate to it, or you could use a partial method such as OnCreated to assign the expression to IsSpecial.
Inside of `partial class Item`

```
partial void OnCreated()
{
     IsSpecial = () => Math.Sqrt(this.Id)%2==0;
}
```

Doing this will always assign IsSpecial, and allow access to "this".

Comment: this works insofar as I can use `this` in an expression this way. However Linq will insist on passing a parameter into the expression used inside a .Where clause, so ()=>xyz should not work, it needs to be (item)=>xyz, which means i have to ignore a passed parameter, and the whole thing gets messy. However this suggestion helped me quite a bit in solving a related problem, so thanks!

Comment: @HugoRune Looking at some of your previous comments, I *think* (I actually have no idea) that this would work as per one of the comments as you stated you wanted:
`datacontext.Item.Where(i=>i.IsSpecial() && i.Id>100 && [more properties]`

Comment: yeah, i thought so too, but it turns out that this is not possible in this way. Leaving aside the 'this' issue, this will still not work even if I use a constant instead of 'this'. Reason:IsSpecial is an Expression tree, not a simple function or lambda. Calling `IsSpecial()` is not valid syntax. `I=>i.IsSpecial && i.Id>100` is not valid syntax either, you cannot concatenate expression trees like this. The confusing thing is that if I use a simple delegate or function instead of an Expression<func>>, it will compile and work with normal Linq, but linq-to-sql is a different beast